# $l_{0}$-norm constrained quadratic programming optimization

Tags: quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization, sparsity

I intend to solve for vector $ x \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1} $ by solving the following optimization problem

\begin{align}
\arg \min_{x} \tfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^T Q\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{x}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\text{S.t. } & x_{i}^{min} \leq x_{i} \leq x_{i}^{max} \\ 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{S.t.   } & \|x\|_0 \leq k\\ 
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is a positive definite matrix, and $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1}$.

Obviously if I remove the second constraint it is possible to solve the above using regular constrained quadratic programming (like quadprog command in MATLAB).

I know the $l_{0}$-norm makes the problem non-convex but I was hoping if someone can give me a hint how I could find the solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use integer programming -- add binary variables $y_i$ with constraints $x^{min}_i y_i \leq x_i \leq x^{max}_i y_i$. Then, your cardinality constraint becomes $\sum_i y_i \leq k$. You now have a mixed-integer quadratic program with linear constraints. It is harder to solve than a continuous QP, but at least this is a well-known class of optimization problems and there are already solvers out there that can tackle it; for example, the Gurobi suite has an MIQP solver. You will have to worry about all the usual issues that arise in IP.